# Order by JSONB data type with sequelize literal

Tags: javascript, json, postgresql, sequelize.js, jsonb

I'm currently using this structure to query for all the items:

```js
const filteredItems = await allItems.findAll({
         where: conditions,
         include: associations,
         order: sortingCriteria,
         limit: limit,
         offset: offset,
      });
```

The `sortingCriteria` currently has this structure:

```js
const sortingCriteria = [
      ["price", "ASC NULLS LAST"],
      ["created_at", "DESC NULLS LAST"],
    ]
```

Being `price` and `created_at` fields of the `allItems` table. In the same table I have another field called `details` that has a [JSONB](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) per item.

And I need to add an extra sorting criteria, so I order by some specific data that can be found in that JSONB, with this structure:

```js
details = { 
            "sizes": {
               "height": 10,
               "width": 20,
            },
            "capacities": {
               "volume": 200,
               "weight": 2,
            }
          }
```

> Let's say I want to order by `volume` all the items (and also by `price` and `created_at`, as I already have). How should I include that in `sortingCriteria` ?

The reason of using a JSONB instead of nested tables and JOINs is performace. I have already tried and, having everything in one table, for huge tables, the performance increases tremendously. I use `limit` and `offset` for pagination purposes. I'm using Sequelize version 6.6.2.

Answer (score 1):

For the `order` for the nested `JSONb` column, you'll have to use the `sequelize.literal` method with the `->>` operator.

```
order: [
  [sequelize.literal('details->>\'capacities\'->>\'volume\''), 'ASC']
]
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Actually this should be `[sequelize.literal('details->\'capacities\'->>\'volume\''), 'ASC']`. First `->` then second `->>`